# Spring Boot JDBC-Test DB Connection Leak When running all the tests

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I have structured my test in the following way.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BizServiceTestContextConfig.class})
@JdbcTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@TestPropertySource( {
    "file:${apps.config.root}/test_config/bizservice.test.properties",
    "file:${apps.config.root}/test_config/dcs.test.properties"
})
@PropertySource(name = PropSourceKey.SCHEDULER_PROPERTIES, value = "file:${apps.config.root}/config/scheduler.properties")
@PropertySource(name = PropSourceKey.MESSAGING_PROPERTIES, value = "file:${apps.config.root}/config/messaging.properties")
public abstract class BizServiceTest {

}
```

For each test class I have extended this class to avoid code duplication.So a typical test class would look like this.

```
public class SystemParameterServiceImplTest extends BizServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private SystemParameterService systemParameterService;

    @Test
    public void testA() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void testB() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void testC() throws Exception {

    }


}
```

I have currently 66 test cases running, all which connect to a pre-initialized the MySQL Db Schema, and run the tests accessing this database. All run on transactions which are rollbacked at the end. The problem I am facing is that, all my tests run and do not release the DB connections. So the more tests I write the higher number of db connections it holds on to. This creates kind of a DB connection leak.
[image]
I know the db connections can be increased in an instance like this. But it makes testing highly unscalable. I tried using `@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)` which did not solve the problem. Is there anyway to release the db connections after the class.

Comment: what do you have in this class `BizServiceTestContextConfig` ?

Comment: Each `@ContextConfiguration`, `@TestPropertySource` and some other things lead to loading another Spring context. apparently most of your tests require a different configuration each time loading a new context, creating a new datasource and thus eventually flooding your DB. I would say the issue is not so much in Spring but in the way you are doing your tests.

Comment: @pvpkiran the component scans.

Comment: @M.Deinum so what would be the ideal way to do these tests? Any pointers to a proper approach resource. None of the help there teaches you how to do beyond a single test class.

Comment: Use a single configuration for all your tests it will automatically be reused. As soon as you start adding `@TestPropertySource`, `@PropertySource` or start using `@MockBean` etc. you are basically creating a new instance of your application. As Spring Test will cache 32 of those you might end up with a lot of test instances.

Comment: Having a super class with all the configuration and extending that class, can this be a problem? @M.Deinum

Comment: If that is the only thing you have and you don't use `@MockBean` and/or `@SpyBean` that shouldn't be a problem. Which could actually indicate you have an issue in your code and not so much in your tests.

Comment: But other than the tests, I cant find any problem. The more tests are introduced the higher the connections that are made. I was constantly running show process-list on mariadb and it shows that as each test class starts, it adds new processes add up to the processlist. @M.Deinum

Comment: Then you aren't only extending the test class but also have additional configurations or are doing weird things in your test or application code. However the code you have posted here is too small to give you an answer.

Comment: The only weird thing I think we may have done is foregoing embedded DB support and wiring the actual DB instance to run the tests, which is vital since our Data model is too complex to be mocked or included in Embedded dbs. Looks like for each test class context it creates a connection pool but doesn't release it once the class is over. So I used a concrete Data Source[Hikari] implementation and got rid of the pool @ AfterClass. Also since spring caches service implementations across test had to kill off the context afterclass  with @DirtiestContext. Connections are released properly now.

Comment: @DirtiestContext saved our day, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only weird thing I think we may have done is foregoing embedded DB support and wiring the actual DB instance to run the tests, which is vital since our Data model is too complex to be mocked or included in Embedded dbs.

ooks like for each test class context it creates a connection pool but doesn't release it once the class is over.

> So I used a concrete Data Source[Hikari] implementation and explicitly
>   got rid of the pool @ AfterClass.

Also since spring caches service implementations across test had to kill off the context afterclass with @DirtiestContext. Connections are released properly now.